# Hide div when searchParams are does not exist in URL

Tags: javascript, html

i work on web base apps, i work using python, html and flask as framework. i heve 3 program file, 1 is processing.py, 2 is server.py, and 3 index.html. when firstly running it will go to index.html, the program need zipfile (contain 4 CSV file) as input. everything work well except the radio button still showing when the input not yet entered (firstly running). i'm using 1 page consept with 3 flows (initial run -> input selection -> process result).i want to hide the radio button div when the file not entered yet(firstly running) and after the submit button pressed (on input selection flows) because the value is not there already, i want to hide the div but it didnt work like i want. heres my code

```
<div id="form_comparison" class=pf-5">
  <form id="comparison_list" action="http://localhost:5000/process" method="POST">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th><input class="comparison" type="radio" name="comparison" id="first" value="data1"></th>
        <th><label for="first" id="first_choice"></label></br></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><input class="comparison" type="radio" name="comparison" id="second" value="data2"></th>
        <th><label for="second" id="second_choice"></label></br></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><input class="comparison" type="radio" name="comparison" id="third" value="data3"></th>
        <th><label for="third" id="third_choice"></label></br></th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
      <button for submit/>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
var url_string = windows.location.href;
var url= new URL(url_string);
var list_data = url.searchParams.getAll("list_data");

document.getElementById("first_choice").innerHTML = list_data[0]
document.getElementById("second_choice").innerHTML = list_data[1]
document.getElementById("third_choice").innerHTML = list_data[2]
document.getElementById("first").value = list_data[0]
document.getElementById("second").value = list_data[1]
document.getElementById("third").value = list_data[2]
</script>
```

i laready tried something like this :

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            if('{{list_data}}'==0){
                $('#form_comparison').hide();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

it keeps the div hidden even after the value is sended, and i tried this `$('div.form_comparison:empty').hide();` it still doesn't work.
how can i make it work properly like i want ?, thanks in advance

this is the URL and pict of URL on browser

1. firstly running
   [image]
   `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`
2. when input entered (input selection flow)
   [image]
   `http://localhost:5000/uploader?filename=4data1dummy.zip&list_data=rekap2015.csv&list_data=edit-rekap-DBD-2013.csv&list_data=edit-rekap-DBD-2014.csv&list_data=dummy1.csv`
3. process result
   [image]
   `http://localhost:5000/proses`

Comment: It's `innerHTML` not `innetHTML`

Comment: This does not look right at all => `{{list_data}}`

Comment: @yunzen ah sorry, thats my bad, actually it innerHTML i got typo there

Comment: It's not clear to me why you are using JS in this case for the task. You earlier said you use Python. So my recommendation is to use Python to populate the inputs

Comment: i'm sorry, ill edit my post first to make it clear

Comment: Question ? you want to hide the `form` if there are NO `searchParams` in `windows.location.href;`

Comment: yes, that will do too, i want to hide it when it not used anymore @AlwaysHelping

Comment: so there will sometime `searchParams`  in your `windows.location.href;` and sometime empty  ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes, at firstly running and after input selction it will empty

Comment: Can you show us how the searchParams looks like from the `windows.location.href` ? Please

Comment: i added the pict on the post @AlwaysHelping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getAll()` method return an `array` of data - You can the check `params` with by checking its length if the `list_data.length` is == `0` then hide the form or `else` do not do anything.

Also, i have used `textContent` to show the text for label since `innerHTML` is **NOT** recemended to apply simply a `text`.

**Live Demo:**  (searchParams **exist** in the URL)

```js
var url_string = 'http://localhost:5000/uploader?filename=4data1dummy.zip&list_data=rekap2015.csv&list_data=edit-rekap-DBD-2013.csv&list_data=edit-rekap-DBD-2014.csv&list_data=dummy1.csv'
//var url_string = window.location.href;
var url = new URL(url_string);
var list_data = url.searchParams.getAll("list_data");
document.getElementById("first_choice").textContent = list_data[0]
document.getElementById("second_choice").textContent = list_data[1]
document.getElementById("third_choice").textContent = list_data[2]
document.getElementById("first").value = list_data[0]
document.getElementById("second").value = list_data[1]
document.getElementById("third").value = list_data[2]

$(function() {
  if (list_data.length == 0) {
    $('#form_comparison').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form_comparison" class="pf-5">
  <form id="comparison_list" action="http://localhost:5000/process" method="POST">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th><input class="comparison" type="radio" name="comparison" id="first" value="data1"></th>
        <th><label for="first" id="first_choice"></label><br></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><input class="comparison" type="radio" name="comparison" id="second" value="data2"></th>
        <th><label for="second" id="second_choice"></label><br></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><input class="comparison" type="radio" name="comparison" id="third" value="data3"></th>
        <th><label for="third" id="third_choice"></label><br></th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
      <button>
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

If you are are no params in the `window.location.href` when you load the page the form will be `hidden`.

**Live Demo:** (**NO** searchParams **found** in the URL)

```js
var url_string = 'http://localhost:5000/proses' //no params
//var url_string = window.location.href;
var url = new URL(url_string);
var list_data = url.searchParams.getAll("list_data");
document.getElementById("first_choice").textContent = list_data[0]
document.getElementById("second_choice").textContent = list_data[1]
document.getElementById("third_choice").textContent = list_data[2]
document.getElementById("first").value = list_data[0]
document.getElementById("second").value = list_data[1]
document.getElementById("third").value = list_data[2]

$(function() {
  if (list_data.length == 0) {
    $('#form_comparison').hide();
    console.log('No Search Params Found - Form is hidden')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form_comparison" class="pf-5">
  <form id="comparison_list" action="http://localhost:5000/process" method="POST">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th><input class="comparison" type="radio" name="comparison" id="first" value="data1"></th>
        <th><label for="first" id="first_choice"></label><br></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><input class="comparison" type="radio" name="comparison" id="second" value="data2"></th>
        <th><label for="second" id="second_choice"></label><br></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><input class="comparison" type="radio" name="comparison" id="third" value="data3"></th>
        <th><label for="third" id="third_choice"></label><br></th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
      <button>
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: oh my god length used for measurement, why I didn't realize before. its working, thanks very much for your help

Comment: @HazelR happy to help. THanks alot. I just wanted to make sure that i help you correctly that why i wanted to clarify things. Happy coding :)

Comment: you're a nice person, thanks a lot again, happy coding :)

Comment: @HazelR Also, i have used `textContent` to show the text for label since `innerHTML` is not recemended to be used to apply simply a `text` to better coding practice :)

Comment: okay I will do that, thanks for the advice :) @AlwaysHelping